# Finding correlations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Just want to know if the following can be done ENTIRELY in SQL Server

I have a table which has 3 columns - `SENTENCE ID (PK)`, `SENTENCE` (strings of arbitrary length), `PATTERNS` (these are 2 or 3 word patterns which are found in the `SENTENCE`).

I need to find the correlation of all the distinct `PATTERNS` with each other.

If I do it externally (using python and ODBC) I need to go through the following steps

FOR each distinct PATTERN

1. Get the count of PATTERN
2. Find all the sentence IDs that have that PATTERN
3. Get counts of all PATTERNS that occur in the above sentence IDs
4. Append the current PATTERN and its count (as columns) to the table in step3.
5. keep appending the above table as rows to the result table

Next

Comment: Most likely you can do this in SQL, since you can even fallback to using more procederal code with cursors if you don't find a set based method.  In step #4 though, it is not clear how you would structure multiple patterns.  whether you would have denormalized repeating columns, or if stored in a seperate one-to-many table, etc.

Comment: How are the patterns represented?  Can you give some examples?

Comment: You could definitely do it with a cursor, need some example data and results to see if there's a set based way.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that PATTERN follows the form of a `like` expression.  And, that you want to count a pattern for a sentence only once.

If so, you can do the following.  Get the matches between all sentences and patterns:

```
with sp as (
       select s.sentenceID, p.pattern, count(*) over (partition by p.pattern) as NumSentences
       from Sentences s join
            Patterns p
            on s.sentence like p.pattern
     )
select sp1.pattern, sp2.pattern,
       sp1.pattern as Pattern1Count, sp2.pattern as Pattern2Count,
       count(*) as BothCount
from sp sp1 join
     sp sp2
     on sp1.pattern < sp2.pattern    -- <= if you want counts for a single pattern
group by sp1.pattern, sp2.pattern
```

You don't explicitly say what kind of output you want, but this should be sufficient.

So, with some reasonable assumptions, you can do this in SQL.